# Flutter - Android intent-filter with Google Oauth

Tags: android, flutter, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have built a Flutter application with Google Oauth, but I encountered an obstacle with intent-filter.

I use https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2_client package for sign in.

I created an Android Credential in Google Api Console what give me only a client_id (in this example that is: 'abc').

My sign in function is:

```
GoogleOAuth2Client client = GoogleOAuth2Client(
                                customUriScheme: "my.test.app",
                                redirectUri: "my.test.app://oauth2redirect");

OAuth2Helper oauth2Helper = OAuth2Helper(client,
                                grantType: OAuth2Helper.AUTHORIZATION_CODE,
                                clientId: 'abc',
                                scopes: [
                                  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
                                ]);

var resp = await oauth2Helper.get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files');
```

I added intent-filter to main/AndrodiManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="com.linusu.flutter_web_auth.CallbackActivity" >
      <intent-filter android:label="flutter_web_auth">
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:scheme="my.test.app" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

When sign-in function is running, google says me: "Custom schemes cannot have authority".

Okay... I tried with 'http://my.test.app/oauth2redirect' -> redirect uri mismatch.
I downloaded the JSON from API console and i see my Android credential has only 2 redirect_uri: "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost". Where does this come from and where can i add more redirect uri?

I changed Android Credential to Web application where i can add custom redirect uri.
I added a fake address to Web credential: "http://my.test.app". This credential give me a client_id and a secret.

Modified the sign_in function:

```
GoogleOAuth2Client client = GoogleOAuth2Client(
                                customUriScheme: "my.test.app",
                                redirectUri: "http://my.test.app");

OAuth2Helper oauth2Helper = OAuth2Helper(client,
                                grantType: OAuth2Helper.AUTHORIZATION_CODE,
                                clientId: 'abc2',
                                clientSecret: 'acb3',
                                scopes: [
                                  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
                                ]);
```

SUCCESS: Google login is working and redirect to http://my.test.app, but the prodecure get stuck. Browser says me: "The site can't be reached" and Android app does not intercept the response. Why??

I dont think my fake site should be exist, isn't it??

I think the redirect uri get an authorization code in query params, my app intercept it and oauth2_client package handle the response.

Why get stuck it in the browser?

Is this an intent problem? I didn't configure something well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: I have to redirect to a reverse DNS notion of the client ID and have to use Android Credential (only with client_id)

In my case:

```
android:scheme="com.googleusercontent.apps.XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

customUriScheme="com.googleusercontent.apps.XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
redirectUri: "com.googleusercontent.apps.XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:/"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Couldn't find any solution until your comment - no documentation of this anywhere